# Similar parallelogram within parallelogram, calculating ratio of areas

Tags: probability, geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-probability

Here are two questions from my probability textbook:

> **481.** A floor is paved with tiles, each tile being a rhomboid whose breadth measured perpendicularly between two opposite sides is $a$, and perpendicularly between the other two opposite sides is $b$; and one of the diagonals is $d$. A stick of length $c$ is thrown upon the floor so as to fall parallel to this diagonal. Show that the chance that it lies entirely on one tile is $\left(1-{c\over{d}}\right)^2$.
>
> **482.** A circle, of diameter $c$, is thrown down on the same floor, show that the chance that it lies on one tile is $\left(1 - {c\over a}\right)\left(1 - {c\over b}\right)$.

Here's the answer in the back of my book:

[image]

I follow everything, up until the following equality in the last line:$${{\text{area}\,oadb}\over{\text{area}\,OADB}} = {{(a-c)(b-c)}\over{ab}},$$which is not justified. Why is this equality true?

Comment: That is a very careless answer. It seems that $a$ and $b$ are being reused to denote corners of the inner parallelogram; and this is borne out by "...the area $oadb$". But then they are used as lengths again in the expression $\frac{(a-c)(b-c)}{ab}$. It took me a while to decipher all this! Also, it should make some effort to justify what @heropup's answer explains (but perhaps this was already explained in the text?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is one of those situations where the equality holds because it is a ratio of areas, not because each area actually equals the respective numerator and denominator.  That is to say, $$|oadb| \ne (a-c)(b-c), \quad |OADB| \ne ab,$$ but it *is* true that $$|oadb| = m(a-c)(b-c), \quad |OADB| = mab,$$ for some constant of proportionality $m > 0$.  The fact that this $m$ is the same for both parallelograms is a consequence of the fact that they have the same angles (but are not necessarily similar).  Thus, when you take the ratio of these quantities, the result follows.

What is this $m$?  Well, if $\angle AOB = \angle aob = \theta$, then we might say $$a = AO \sin \theta,$$ hence $$|OADB| = AO \cdot b = ab \csc \theta,$$ and the same argument gives $$|oadb| = ao \cdot (b-c) = (a-c)(b-c) \csc \theta.$$  So $m = \csc \theta$ and we can confirm that for the special case $\theta = 90^\circ$, we get $m = \csc \theta = 1$, the parallelograms become rectangles, and the areas do in fact equal $ab$ and $(a-c)(b-c)$ respectively.